# Sympy comparing expressions after evaluation

Tags: sympy, evaluation

I want a function that will compare, whether evaluated and non-evaluated expressions are different. So this:

```
import sympy.parsing.sympy_parser as spp

string = "x+x"
exp1 = spp.parse_expr(string, evaluate = False)
exp2 = spp.parse_expr(string)
print exp1
print exp2
print exp1 == exp2
```

Should output

```
x + x
2*x
False
```

And the same code with `string = "x**2+1"` should output

```
x**2+1
x**2+1
True # But it outputs False here too.
```

Yes, I have read [the FAQ](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Faq), but it doesn't explain how to fix/work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant issue is https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/5904.

When `evaluate=False`, the `args` property is not sorted:

```
>>> a = sympify('x**2 + 1', evaluate=False)
>>> b = sympify('x**2 + 1')
>>> a == b
False
>>> a.args
(x**2, 1)
>>> b.args
(1, x**2)
```

I don't believe (but you should check on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sympy) to be sure) that there is a built-in way to resolve this. The best approach depends on what you are trying to accomplish with this comparison.

The discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sympy/LU5DQGJJhfc/_Le_u8UGtx0J  (though outdated!) suggests making a custom comparison function, perhaps using the `_sorted_args` property:

```
>>> a._sorted_args
[1, x**2]
>>> b._sorted_args
[1, x**2]
```

Comment: Have I understood correctly: comparing ._sorted_args instead of expressions themselves will result in correct output.

Comment: @RuRo not necessarily, you'd need a comparison function that can recursively compare the `_sorted_args` of each of the objects in `_sorted_args`. Just comparing `_sorted_args` won't work for expressions like `1 + sin(1 + x**2)` and `1 + sin(x**2 + 1)`.

Comment: hmm... That's complicated and doesn't solve it fully, I want arrangement to matter, let me try to give some examples: x + x and 2x - false, x + 1 and 1 + x - false, x^3 + 1 (evaluated) and x^3 + 1 (not evaluated) - true